# Offline installation of VS Express 2010 - what about .NET 4.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-framework

I would need to know whether or not the offline version of VS Express contains .NET 4.0 as well? I do not think so.
I know that using the web installer, the .NET 4.0 is automatically downloaded when needed.
What about offline version?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [standalone (offline) installer for .NET 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0a391abd-25c1-4fc0-919f-b21f31ab88b7)